# Exchange 2010 Resource Room Bookings

Tags: exchange-2010

I have an Exchange 2010 setup with a number of Resource Rooms setup as per the guides floating around. All is working well and as expected. I ahve set it up so no conflcits are allowed, we have no delegates at all, and all requests are accepted as long as they meet the basic guidleines.

I've just had a user today want to make multiple bookings for their 'group' in a few calendars but they keep being rejected because the user doing the bookings has already made other bookings for that date/time in other rooms - so they get the 'Declined: Conflict' message as you would expect. So the user is in conflcit - not the resource room.

So what I need I guess is a way to allow a person to make mutliple bookings in different rooms without causing a conflict. But I still want the rooms not being able to be double booked.

Is this possible??

Or, is there a way to book a room without having a person attached to it?? So its jsut a room booking, shows up in the Calendar but the person who made the booking doesn't show up in the attendees.

Any thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Set-CalendarProcessing cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046.aspx)

Let's say you have a colleague called "Guy Organizer", who wants to override the Request policy for a room box called "TheResourceRoomMailbox". This should do the trick:

```
Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity "TheResourceRoomMailbox" -AutomateProcessing AutoAccept -RequestOutOfPolicy GuyOrganizer@company.com
```

If you add delegates in the future, they'll still be able to review and cancel the auto-accepted appointments.

Comment: Chhers Mathais, I'll have a crack at that today. Apologies for lateness of reply

Comment: This seems to have solved the issue for me for one particular room calendar. Cheers for that ;)